# Using an undefined variable as a dictionary key in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to recreate the Pokemon Damage Calculator in Python from: https://github.com/Zarel/honko-damagecalc/blob/master/js/data/move_data.js

His dictionaries begin with:

```
var MOVES_RBY = {
    '(No Move)': {
        bp: 0,
        type: 'Normal',
        category: 'Physical'
    },
```

I have this in my Python script but without the `var` and it returns the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>    NameError: name 'bp' is not defined

How do I define `bp` to use it in a similar fashion?

Comment: Your code doesn't look like python

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, dictionary keys are implicitly converted to strings. This isn't the case in Python. So the equivalent Python code would be:

```
MOVES_RBY = {
  '(No Move)': {
    'bp': 0,
    'type': 'Normal',
    'category': 'Physical'
  },
}
```